# Vertex AI pricing model training and prediction (endpoints)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I want to ask about the pricing calculation details, I am still confused when reading the documentation. I will do a training model such as XGBoost or Scikit-Learn to forecast the data, I need to train the model in region asia-southeast2 (Jakarta) using the lowest specification. After training, I want to deploy it in Endpoints and access it via API.

For example, this is the information:

- Training process: 2 Hours
- Size Model: 250 MB
- It will be hit 600x (Online prediction)

My question is, how about the pricing from training until the model can be hit via API from these information? The training pricing, deploy to endpoint pricing, 1 hit API pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Pricing for AutoML models pays for the three main activities: **model training**, **deploying to an endpoint**, and **using the model to make predictions**. You can browse through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing) to see the pricing information. Usually, the pricing depends on per hour of usage.